# Ruby PG gem Connections Not ClosingPG gem Connections Not Closing

Tags: ruby, sinatra, pg

`PostgreSQL` is installed on my workstation and I host an admin website (`Sinatra` using the `PG` gem on `nginx`) that only I have access too.

Every so often I get thei following error:

```
PG::ConnectionBad - FATAL:  sorry, too many clients already
```

`max_connections` is indeed set to 100, but I'm using two on any page at any time.  Looking at the `pg_stat_activity`, I see two simple `SELECT`s that are not problematic:

```
SELECT * FROM twils ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 30   client backend
SELECT mdate FROM params WHERE mkey = $1    client backend
```

Both of these are completed before the page has time to even render (comparable speed) and should not stay open.  So either I'm mistaken in that I need to force these closed, or they are not closing at the end of the page, basically **garbage collection**.

Since `PG` connections are stateless and don't carry from page to page, I am under the impression the end of the page means all connections closed for the user.  I thought it was automatic.  Am I wrong to assume this?  Am I to deliberately perform a `conn.close` or `conn.finish` on every connection?

```
conn = PG.connect( dbname: 'hq' )
```

Comment: Can you supply the connection set up code or which framework/code you're using to make calls to the database?

Comment: @iain Done.  Couldn't be more simple.

Comment: I don't use the PG gem but I would suggest perhaps wrapping database calls in a block (as [File.open](http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2012/10/01/using-ruby-blocks-to-ensure-resources-are-cleaned-up/) does) with [`finish`](https://deveiate.org/code/pg/PG/Connection.html#method-i-finish) to make sure they're closed, and put those selects into stored procedures to see if that helps. Trying a library like [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) that will happily take SQL strings and will manage the connection might be worth investigating. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: I can close connections, not a problem.  Just wondering about default procedures with garbage collection as it's not documented in the `PG::connection` pages.  I can test other implementations later, but thought I'd just throw it out there in case I was missing something.  Thx.